# Same websites in different operating systems

Tags: browser, operating-system, cross-browser

If we use the same browser, do we always have the same result from an OS to another ? or we should test the visual components in each possible OS ?

Comment: The layout should be more or less the same, with some small differences in the details. But I will let people with more experience answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Even though browsers behave mostly in the same way, there are small differences on the same browsers across different OS's.

Here is a list of things that you have to keep in mind:

- Different OS's means different fonts, also antialising does not work 
  the same on each OS. This can cause some fonts to look smooth and
  slick on Windows FF for example but quite pixelated on Ubuntu FF.
- UI elements are OS based so your combo boxes for example will have a different look depending on the OS. You can check out a complete
  list [here](http://designerstoolbox.com/designresources/elements/).

As a conclusion, from a designers point of view, it is highly recommended to check the look&feel of your site on all Browser/OS combinations.